# Density of uniformly chosen random point inside triangle

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Imagine the triangle inside of the points $(0,0), (0,1)$ and $(1,0).$ Let $(X,Y)$ be a uniformly chosen random point from the triangle. Then find the joint density of $X$ and $Y$.

The answer is $f_{XY}(x,y)=2$ if $(x,y)$ is in the triangle and $0$ if $(x,y)$ is not.

Can someone explain why that answer is true? I tried using the convolution formula but didn't know what to use for the marginal densities of $X$ and $Y$. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $f_{XY} (x,y)$ is constant inside the triangle since $(X,Y)$ is uniformly chosen. Then the integral of the p.d.f. over the triangle $T$ with base $b$ and height $h$ reduces like this:

$$\iint \limits_Tf_{XY} dA = bh/2 \cdot f_{XY} = 1$$

And since $b = h =1$, $f_{XY}=2$ inside the triangle.